# Changing Usernames

Tags: users

I'm interested in granting the permission to change usernames to one of my member groups but this doesn't seem possible. Is there anyway to grant permission to edit usernames for members that are not Super Administrators? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going down the wrong path on this one. The only reason the other member group needed to edit the usernames was because the stand-alone member registration module wasn't configured to set the desired username format. I simply made adjustments to that form and now the need to edit usernames will likely never arise and if it does I can handle a few isolated cases such as name changes etc.

Under EE 2.5.2 it does not seem possible to edit the username unless you are a Super Administrator or have modified the core files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the Member Group settings under Control Panel access, do you have "Can access MEMBERS section" set to "Yes"

And in the Member Group settings under the Control Panel Administration section, do you have the "Can administrate members accounts" option set to "Yes"?

Those two settings should do it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and yes I absolutely have those two settings set to "Yes" but only Super Administrators are able to edit the usernames. The other member group with these settings enabled can edit every other aspect of the member account except for the username.